# Getting Error While Sending Mail on client.send(message)?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one mail.aspx.cs with following code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@foo.bar.com"));
        message.Subject = "This is my subject";
        message.Body = "This is the content";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(message);
    }
```

And web.config settings

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="abc xyz" password="abc" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Getting failure error while sending mail on page load on following line

```
 client.Send(message); mail sending fail,
```

i am new in asp.net,guide me correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: when u post any question. Don't post your original username password any body can misuse it. Please replace it with dummy user name and password.

Comment: Not the solution, but you should use `using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage()){... using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()){...}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com");
```

And

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="nitinturankar3@gmail.com">
```

Must be the same!

Comment: remove whitespaces in this line too:         <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="NITIN TURANKAR" password="mkoZAQ!@#$%()     " defaultCredentials="true" />

Answer (score 0):

You are using a username with empty space `userName="NITIN TURANKAR"`, this is wrong

Comment: Means Space Not Allow?

Comment: Yes AFAIK username can not include spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string SendMail(string toList, string from, string ccList, string subject, string body)
{

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    string msg = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.To.Add(toList);
        //if (attachments != "")
        //{
        //    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachments));
        //}
        if (ccList != null && ccList != string.Empty)
            message.Bcc.Add(ccList);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = body;
        // We use gmail as our smtp client
        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            "Email", "password");

        smtpClient.Send(message);
        msg = "Successful<BR>";

        string message1 = "Your Query has been Submited Successfully";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return msg;
}
```

try port replace to 587 Also.